# Does the cat command pass back a file or the contents of the file?

Tags: command-line, grep, cat

Compare the following commands:

```
cat f.txt | grep "someText" 
grep "someText" f.txt
```

They both seem to work. But the documentation for cat says cat outputs the contents of the file rather than the file name and grep command takes file name but not file contents (correct me if I am wrong), then why does the first command work since it is feeding grep with the file contents rather than the file name.

Another question: they both work but why would one use the first line instead of the second, the first one is just redundant?

Answer (score 9):

In your first example

```
cat f.txt | grep "someText"
```

`grep` doesn't get a filename argument, only a string to search for. In that case `grep` will read the text to search from standard input. In this case that standard input is piped in from the output of `cat f.txt`, **which outputs the content of the file** not the filename.
What you also could have done to make `grep` read from stdin is to use:

```
< f.txt grep "someText"
```

Using `cat` is quite often redundant on its own (independent of `grep`) and can be replaced by the input redirection as above. I would always use the second form in your example, unless you have to do some preprocessing on the input.

Comment: I see. I think I should learn more about linux pipe online then, thank you

Comment: But doesn't grep only take filename as its argument?

Comment: @kun No like I indicated (if you don't specify any options) the first argument is the string to search for. If there are more arguments, then those is/are the file(s) to search through. Look at `man grep` and carefully study the SYNOPSIS in there.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I am saying that grep's last operand should be a file name rather than the contents of the file, which are different, right? I completely understand its first operand is the pattern string.

Comment: @Kun run grep with only one argument. for example `grep hello`. This will hang and wait for input from stdin. The pipe just says "do `grep <pattern>`, but instead of getting input from stdin, get it from the output on the other side of the pipe, which is `cat`"

Comment: @ Liam I still don't really understand. The man page for grep explains it needs a file name, not the contents. The pipe is giving the grep the file contents rather than the file name, right?

Comment: @kun, the [grep man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) says `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]` -- that means the only required argument is the pattern. You may provide one or more files, but the square brackets indicate the files are optional. The man page says (the 2nd sentence): "If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given, grep searches *standard input*."

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for piping in while I was making/eating dinner ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two main reasons for using `cat` as in your first example:

1. As a place-holder for some other command or long and complicated pipeline of commands.

   e.g. if you're writing a script or one-liner to process a huge file, or data from a `psql`/`mysql` or `wget` or `jq` etc query, you might save (some of) the input to a sample file and use `cat sample` as input until you get your script or one-liner right.  Then just replace the `cat` with the actual command or pipeline.

   Similarly, it's a useful place-holder if your purpose is to teach someone about pipes.

   (Many people call this a Useless Use of Cat or UUOC.  That's largely because they're smug and like to use their allegedly superior knowledge to beat down novices rather than help them learn - the terrible crime of using `cat` rather than `<` is so important that it can't be ignored as if it were just a trivial detail.  the world would end, it would be a `cat`astrophe.)
2. When you don't want a program to know the filename(s) of the input file(s).   e.g.  `cat * | grep ...` is different to `grep ... *`.

   This doesn't matter very often but when it does, it can matter a lot.

   For `grep`, you can suppress listing of the filenames with `-h`, but other programs have no such option - `wc`, for example, will always output the filenames and per-file counts, even if you don't want them.

   You can, of course, use something like `wc * | tail -1 | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}'` but that doesn't work if you're doing something like `find . -type f -exec wc {} +` and the list of filenames generated by `find` exceeds the shell's maximum command line length - in that case, you get multiple 'total' lines (and there's no way of distinguishing between an actual total line and a file with the name 'total' in `wc`'s output).

   `find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc` produces just one line of output (the totals) no matter how many files `find` finds, none or one or many.

   (`wc` really needs both `--totals-only` and `--no-totals` options.)

Comment: Another practical use of using `cat` is to ensure that the program the data is being fed to can handle a pipe correctly. If you feed a file with shell redirection `<` the process will still be able to seek in it, which it won't be able to do if you pipe the output of `cat`. So `cat` can be used to check for compatibility when you might later want to put more complex processing in the pipeline.